# How to convert SVGs to GIFs with ImageMagick?

Tags: svg, image-processing, imagemagick, gif, graphicsmagick

I'd like to convert a SVG that has a reference to a GIF inside into a final GIF.
The SVG shows fine with the GIF in a browser, but converting the file from SVG to GIF results in only converting the first frame of the GIF.

that's my test.svg:

```
<svg id="TEST" data-name="TEST" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">

<image width="2000" height="2000" xlink:href="input.gif"/>

</svg>
```

imagemagick command:
`magick convert test.svg output.gif`

the result is that only the first frame gets converted into a GIF, not the whole sequence.

Anything I can adjust with the ImageMagick command to make this work?

Comment: Not possible with ImageMagick. It will only make one output file.

Comment: Got it, thanks @fmw42, are there any other cmd-line tools that can do that or would I need a completely different approach? Need that feature for batch-processing a large amount of images.

Comment: I do not know of any.